Usage of volitional + というところ?
The character is wondering where to take the relationship next and thinks

いざ先に進もうというところで一線を引いてしまうんだろう

What does というところ mean here? I understand the first part is "I try to move forward" and the second is "I draw a line" but how do they connect? is it a meaning similar to "but"?

というところ is ordinary quotative と + plain verb 言う + noun 所. So, structurally, it follows the normal rules: we have an attributive verb clause describing a noun that means "place" or "scene" (i.e., a specific physical location) literally, and thus "matter/concern" or "point in time" metaphorically. The relevant sense in Jisho's listing is #10. Phrases like "about to" or "on the verge of" aren't noun phrases in English, of course; those translations really correspond to the combination ところで. I.e., at a given point in time (the one specified by the beginning point of some other attributive verb clause), the main clause happens.
The speech described by 言う is presumably directed inward, given the context you describe. という here is serving the purpose that you might expect from と[思]{おも}う, but I understand the latter is more about expressing opinions to others - your "inner voice" is still a voice.
The volitional form, of course, is broader than "try to...".
Thus, I make it: "When I think 'well then, I should move forward!', ...".
Filling in the rest of the sentence around that (with a proper understanding of てしまう and んだろう) is left as an exercise.

I take the whole sentence is
"Just when I think I should move forward, I end up drawing a line, don't I"?

Sounds pretty good to me.
